# How to save specified excel data to database using c#

Tags: c#, excel

Excel data is like this
[image: Excel data is like this]

I want save data in database like this
[image: I want save data in database like this]

how to write the code in c#.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please have a look at the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get you started with [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently your question is lacking lots of information, like your current code and what you have tried etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this Blog:
https://paragon-inc.com/resources/blogs-posts/easy_excel_interaction_pt1 (and follow ups)

there you find the information about how to do it with the use of epplus library.

hope this helps.

Comment: ah by the way, part 6 of the blog-series should be best start for you.

Comment: Thank you for ur help.. I'll look into it.